# How to expect error when parsing through arguments? - Angular6, Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine

I have written a function called `saveToken(token)` which takes a `string` argument and saves it to the local storage in **angular6**. I am writing the tests for it in **jasmine**, and want that the test case throws an error when there are either no arguments given or the token is in an invalid format.

The problem is that when I run the test case it stops before even running the test case because there are no arguments (or invalid arguments) provided to the function, so it never runs.

i wanted to know if there was another approach that I could try (something perhaps called `toRaiseException` or similar) , or whether this is related to the error handling (which there is none frankly), so I may need to add some error handling first before proceeding to the tests.

Here is my code:

**jwt.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class JwtService {
  /**
   * This method takes the token as an argument and saves it into the local storage.
   *
   * @param  token
   * @method saveToken
   * @return
   */
  saveToken(token: string) {
    window.localStorage['jwtToken'] = token;
  }
}
```

**jwt.service.spec.ts**

```
import { TestBed, inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { JwtService } from './jwt.service';

const TOKEN = "SomeToken";

describe('JwtService', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        JwtService
      ]
    });
  });


  //saveToken

  it('Call to function is made when there is no access token in arguments', inject([JwtService],
    (service: JwtService) => {
      expect(function() { service.saveToken(null); }).toThrow();
    }));

  it('Call to function is made when the access token is in the wrong format', inject([JwtService],
    (service: JwtService) => {
      let data = {"Token": TOKEN}
      expect(function() { service.saveToken(data); }).toThrow();
    }));


});
```

Comment: My apologies, but I'm a bit confused - `null` is a perfectly valid value to set a string to in Javascript.  Since your code does no testing of the parameters passed, this will not throw any sort of error.  It looks almost as if you are expecting an incorrect type to cause an error - are you looking for something like `typeof`?  Good article on JavaScript types [here](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-javascript-types-and-reliable-type-checking/#typeof-operator)

Comment: @dmcgrandle please look at the function after that. I actually wrote null as an argument so that I could test the second function without having Karma to crash midway. If I do not put any arguments the same error comes for this function. I might have not made this clear so I see how you may be confused. Apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put your test case up in a [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-53631820?file=app%2Fjwt.service.ts) to test out your assertion that: *"when I run the test case it stops before even running the test case because there are no arguments (or invalid arguments) provided to the function, so it never runs."*

I thought this was odd, and not what I would expect, so after I set up the Stackblitz, I put in a console.log into the `saveToken()` method.  If you click on the Console (bottom left of the Jasmine test window in the Stackblitz) you will see that the function is indeed called even for the case when no parameters are passed.  I currently have those tests commented out (with an 'x' in the front of the test), but feel free to remove the x and see what I mean.

Typescript is indeed complaining when the function is called without parameters, and again when it is called with the wrong type, so perhaps that is what you meant by your comment, but JavaScript itself is fine with both these cases, which is why I am guessing you want to check for it in your code.

I wrote a new method that is one way to approach this, check out `saveTokenWithErrorChecking()` in the Stackblitz.  It is reproduced here:

```
saveTokenWithErrorChecking(token: string) {
    if(token === undefined) {
        console.log('saveTokenWithErrorChecking() executed and throwing an error');
        throw new Error('no arguments');
    } else if (typeof token !== 'string') {
        console.log('saveTokenWithErrorChecking() throws a type error');
        throw new Error('token is the wrong type');
    } else {
        console.log('saveTokenWithErrorChecking() executed with no error');
        localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', token);
    }
}
```

Lastly you will notice I am using the angular API for localStorage instead of calling the window object directly.  :)

I hope this all helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution, wanted to ask why you did not use `try/catch` with this? Isn't using `if `conditions a bit dirty especially if there is a function that can end up with, say, a possible 10 different issues?

Comment: Sure, there are lots of ways to implement this and I agree - what I did was very simplistic.  My point wasn't to provide a robust production-ready solution (that might be worthy of another StackOverflow question all on it's own), but rather to simply show that the error checking should be done within the method of the service.  How you choose to do that is up to you.  :)